# PHP explode to get path excluding extension

Tags: php

I am having a string as

```
$test = "http://www.abc.com/video/test.mp4";
```

The result I need is

```
$test = "http://www.abc.com/video/test";
```

i.e excluding only the extension.

```
$path_parts = pathinfo($test);
$url_vid =  $path_parts['dirname'];
$url_vid1 = $path_parts['basename'];
// echo $path_parts['extension'], "\n";
$url_vid2 = $path_parts['filename'];
```

these give the seperate dirname, filename etc.
Can anyone help me how to fetch all in one just excluding the extension.

Comment: What about, let's say `http://www.abc.com/video/test.mp4?foo=bar` or `http://www.abc.com/video/?foo=test.mp4` ? Would that occur? And what should be the result?

Comment: no, the url will always be like http://www.abc.com/video/test.mp4

Comment: What about `http://www.abc.com/video/test.file.mp4` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$test = "http://www.abc.com/video/test.mp4";


$new=substr($test,0,strrpos($test,'.'));
echo $new;
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want something like this,

```
 <?php
     $temp = explode(".mp4", "http://www.abc.com/video/test.mp4");
     $url = $temp[0];
     print_r(parse_url($url));
     echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
 ?>
```

output:

```
   Array 
   ( 
     [scheme] => http 
     [host] => www.abc.com 
     [path] => /video/test
   )
   /video/test
```

Source : http://pk1.php.net/parse_url